# Why is my sherbet loosing flavour?

Tags: flavor, sugar, ice-cream, sorbet

I have recently been mixing batches of sherbet using Malic acid, colour, flavouring and granulated sugar. I add all the ingredients and mix it for 10 minutes in a stainless steel drum.
The flavor is very strong to start with, but over a period of 2 weeks it loses all its flavoring.

I am unsure of the reason why, and wonder if anyone could help?

Comment: What is the flavouring?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this myself, but [this website](http://cooking-ez.com/ice-cream-sorbets.php) has some good tips:

- "Simple to prepare because all the quality comes from the quality of fruit used: the better the fruit is, the better your sorbet will be. In others words, if you use tasteless fruits, you will have a tasteless sorbet."
- "...fruit purées lose their flavour, vitamins and colour quickly in the air. If possible, make the fruit purée in your blender at the last minute, then 30 minutes in the freezer, and finally into the machine"

This [website](http://m.tastemag.co.za/article/view/464) simply states:

- "Sorbets are water ices and at their best when freshly made, as they lose flavour in the freezer."